# Parse.com fromJSON function not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse cloud-code function that is resident in Heroku.  I want to create a Parse object from the json that is passed to Heroku, so I'm using the Parse.Object `fromJSON()` function to try to do this:

```
var Vendor = Parse.Object.extend("Vendor");
var vendor = new Vendor();

var myVendor = vendor.fromJSON(json);
```

The above code fails at the final line, with the error message:

```
2015-12-01T02:18:05.446656+00:00 app[web.1]:    var myVendor = vendor.fromJSON(json);
2015-12-01T02:18:05.446656+00:00 app[web.1]:                          ^
2015-12-01T02:18:05.446657+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

Any ideas why I can't get this function working?

Comment: Looks like you have to call `.fromJSON()` in the JSON object (docs: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_fromJSON), but I can't help you any more... I have no experience in Parse.

Comment: @AlejandroIván you beat me too it!

Comment: Sorry, don't fully understand what you mean by having to call `.fromJSON()` "in the JSON object"

Comment: Have you tried `var myVendor = Parse.Object.fromJSON(json)`

Comment: Yep, exact same error: `var user = Parse.Object.fromJSON(json);` Undefined is not a function.

Comment: I thought as much, seen as by extending the `Parse.Object` class you'd get access to that method.   I might write an extension for this sometime this week, looks like a problem thats been requested several times on SO

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get `fromJSON` working then I'd suggest looping over each key in your JSON object and then using Parse's `set` method to assign the value for that key, at which point you could do:

```
// Set the key/value on the object for each entity in the json objet
for(var key of json) 
    vendor.set(key, json[key])

vendor.save(null, {
    success: function(newVendor) {
        console.log(newVendor)
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
})
```

Please bear in mind that I've written this from my phone, so I have not tested the output, but I believe this should be the general direction you go with this problem.

I hope it helps/works.

Comment: Thank you! I really only need the Parse Object without data. I'm using it to set the field for one of my link (relationship) classes.  I stumbled on the fromJSON function when perusing the docs and got frustrated when I couldn't get it working.  Thanks again for your help!